# El internalFrame no cierra

Tags: java, sql, mysqli, formularios, jframe

Se supone que con el siguiente código se cerraría el internalframe dentro del principal pero solo aparece el ícono, y no realiza la acción de cerrarla:

```
public jFrmClientes() {
    initComponents();
    BloquearCajas(false);
    BloquearBotones(true, false);
    CargarRegistros();
    
    setClosable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
}
```

Comment: Esto no "cierra" nada, solo es el constructor de una clase que desconocemos y lo único remotamente comparable es que se pone el valor de *closable* a *true* (es decir, que se puede cerrar). Por favor revisa [ask].

Comment: en caso que deseemos cerrar el formulario interno como se podria realizar?